# Would this relay module work

Tags: relay

I made am making a relay module based on the EC2-3NU relay and just wanted to ask if there was any error in either my circuit or my perfboard layout[image][image]

Comment: the transistor emitter should be connected to ground

Comment: You should also verify that the relay contacts are properly rated for the current you expect the pump to use. A pump will often be an "inductive load".

Comment: Award winning schematic diagram drawing. just saying.

Comment: How do you verify if it can handle Inductive loads? I read the data sheet and am 75% sure it says it can handle 250vac

Answer (score 1):

That LED you have in series with the transistor emitter in your drawing will ruin everything (by taking too much voltage), but it doesn't appear to be present on the circuit board, so that should work

If you want to light a led when the relay is on one way is to put it and its
series resistor in parallel with the relay coil.